# perl's pod2usage(-verbose => 2) shows the source code instead of the formatted documentation

Tags: perl, perldoc

According to the [documentation of Pod::Usage](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.1/lib/Pod/Usage.pm), with `pod2usage(-verbose => 2)` "the entire manpage is printed". However, in some cases, the perl source code for the script is displayed instead of the properly formatted manpage.

Here's an example:

```
use Pod::Usage qw(pod2usage);
pod2usage(-verbose => 2);

__END__

=head1 NAME

Minimal example

=head1 SYNOPSIS

This is the synopsys section.

=cut
```

Running the script:

```
$ perl test.perl            
You need to install the perl-doc package to use this program.
use Pod::Usage qw(pod2usage);
pod2usage(-verbose => 2);

__END__

=head1 NAME

Minimal example

=head1 SYNOPSIS

This is the synopsys section.

=cut
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `pod2usage` uses the command-line program `perldoc`. If this program is not installed, then no formatting is done and you get the full source code in the output.

Note that in the question, the text "`You need to install the perl-doc package to use this program.`" appears in the output to give you a hint about what's going on (but when the help text is long and piped to a pager, this line is not always visible).

Solution: install perldoc (e.g. `apt install perl-doc` on Ubuntu). After this:

```
$ perl test.perl 
NAME
    Minimal example

SYNOPSIS
    This is the synopsys section.
```